# Verify the circumference of the circle formula for a circle of radius r using the arc length formula.

Tags: calculus

Verify the circumference of the circle formula for a circle of radius r using the arc length formula.

How do I complete this problem? Do I use the ellipse equation or the proper circle equation with (x, h) and (y,k)?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: It'll be easiest to do it in polar coordinates -- i.e. with the equation $r=c$ for radius $c$.  Do you know the formula for arc length in polar coordinates (or can you derive it yourself)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it with half a circle that we can assume is centered at the origin:

$$x^2+y^2=r^2\implies y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\;,\;\;y'=-\frac x{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}$$

Thus (the function's even)

$$I:=\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{r^2-x^2}}\;dx=2\int_0^r\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac xr\right)^2}}$$

Substitution

$$x=r\sin u\implies dx=r\cos u\implies$$

$$I=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{r\cos u\;du}{\cos u}=\pi r$$

**Using parametrization in two variables:** we can write the same circle above as

$$(x(t)\,,\,y(t))\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;x(t)=r\cos t\;,\;\;y=r\sin t\;,\;\;0\le t\le2\pi$$

and thus the arclength is given by

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{r^2\sin^2t+r^2\cos^2t}dt=r\int_0^{2\pi}dt=2\pi r$$